# Field for Order in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called `Employee`:

`Employee`:

- `Name`: CharField
- `Email`: EmailField
- `Age`: IntegerField
- **`Ranking`**: IntegerField

My problem comes with the `Ranking` field. The `Ranking` field is supposed to determine an order for the employees, which I determine based on how much work they do. I set this value in **Django admin**.

The problem is that if I add an employee and I put them at `Ranking = 2`, **I have to adjust every single other employee's `Ranking` after 2**. Does this make sense. **How can I avoid this?**

Thanks!

Comment: You could try linked list approach. Replace your `Ranking` field with `EmployeeAbove` field which will be a foreign key pointing to the employee that comes before in the ranking order. This way you need to update maximum 3 employees no matter how many total employees you have in your table.

Comment: Why not use a `FloatField`? If you need to insert in between two values, you use the average between the two. So between `2` and `3`, you can use `2.5`. Between `2` and `2.5` you can use `2.25`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am hesitant to use floats as it seems a bit clunky, but will consider.

Comment: @ShahinMursalov this sounds like an interesting idea. How could i set it up so that two people can't point to one person though?

Comment: @ShahinMursalov You should post this as an answer, although it makes it harder to determine, say, who the 100th employee is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this hasn't been tested but the general idea is to override the `.save()` method so that you can recalculate the rankings for other instances when the ranking of an instance change:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        other_employees = Employee.object.exclude(pk=self.pk).order_by("ranking")
        i = 1
        for employee in other_employees:
            if i == self.ranking:
                i += 1
            employee.ranking = i
            employee.save()
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that this is not production quality code. You should probably do something about race conditions (such as when two people save two `Employee` objects at the same time) and other quirks.